# MongoDB user management

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have two replica set, the primary one I want to disable all users and just the application login will connect to it and on the secondary I want the user to connect it to secondary for reading purpose. I do not want any one to connect with primary replication other than the application. Can this be achievable, please guide.

Like we can achieve this type of solution by SQL Server, I want to implement same in mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. In general all data in a replica set are **replicated**, i.e. they are exactly the same - this includes also user/role details.

Maybe it would be possible to create local users, however by default you don't know which node acts as PRIMARY or SECONDARY (unless you set `Priority 0`).

How do the user connect to your MongoDB? Maybe you can rewrite their connection URL with and append `readPreference=secondaryPreferred`

**Update:**

I don't think the local user will work. You can drop the entire node and connect it to replica set with an empty data directory. The initial synch will copy **all** data to the new node, i.e. it would also overwrite any locally created user account.

Comment: Thank you Wernfried Domscheit. your feedback will help me to make the decision